# Probability after a specific sequence of events?

Tags: probability

I am working on some probability problems (not homework, I'm actually a 24 year old software developer who is doing some number crunching for a personal project) and wondering if someone who understands probability better than me can explain.

I understand that if I was to flip a even sided coin, the chances of getting a heads is 50% or 1/2.  I understand that if I was to flip a coin twice, each independent flip is 1/2 but to get heads twice in a row, I need to multiply the probabilities.  So 1/2 * 1/2 = 0.25 or 25% chance of that happening.

However, my point of confusion comes when you have even more numbers and even more complex sequences.

For example, lets say I flipped a coin 5 times and I got:

```
Heads
Heads
Heads
Tails
Heads
```

What is the probability I get Heads the 6th time? How would you work that out given you already know what happened the last 5 attempts?

For the sake of the maths being easier to distinguish between heads and tails, lets say it's a uneven coin and the probability of a single flip is:

```
Heads: 60%
Tails: 40%
```

EDIT: On further reflection, I guess my real question is what is the chance of a specific set of coin flips occurring, assuming the coins have uneven probability of 60% and 40% as described above.  Please can you try to explain with examples as opposed to using formulas, as my mathematical background is not strong.

Comment: The probability of coin flips are independent - ie. if I flip a coin 30 times and get heads every time, on my 31st flip, the odds of me getting tails would still be 40%, because previous coin flips do not change the odds of a future coin flip. Are you actually referring to coins (independent probability), or something else with dependent probabilities, and were just using coins as an example?

Comment: I guess I am a little confused, but thinking on it in reflection, I guess the real question is what is the probability of a specific set of events occurring.  I.e. Heads, Heads, Heads, Tails, Heads, Heads.

Comment: Or maybe you were thinking, *What are the odds of me getting the sequence* ```Heads Heads Heads Tails Heads Heads```? Edit: I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds of you getting any sequence is, like you mentioned, the multiplication of every term in the sequence : the set $\{H, H, H, T, H, H\}$ can be evaluated as 
$$
P_H \cdot P_H \cdot P_H \cdot P_T \cdot P_H \cdot P_H = P_{Total}
$$
So when $P_H = 60\%$ and $P_T = 40\%$, the probability would be
$$
0.6 \cdot 0.6 \cdot 0.6 \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.6 \cdot 0.6\ = 0.031104
$$

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot now, I had the answer all along then? So it doesn't matter if the probabilities are uneven or what the sequence is, as long as I multiply all the probabilities then it will give me an accurate result of the likelihood of it occurring?

Comment: Will mark as answer, I think you are right.

Comment: @KillerKode You've written "What is the probability I get Heads the 6th time?" in a *complete* sentence, so the target event should be "getting Head the 6th time", regardless of the outcome of the previous five flips.  Therefore, the final answer is *not* the probability that you're looking for.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 In the comments, he specified that what he wrote wasn't what he meant. [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195244/probability-after-a-specific-sequence-of-events/3195274?noredirect=1#comment6575772_3195244) specifies he means the total probability of a set.

Comment: [Comments are *euphemeral*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=comments+ephemeral) on SE.  While we all know what OP intend to say, the wording "**a** specific set of coin flips occurring" in the question body is *ambiguous* and *not specific* at all.  I read this in two senses: "flips" means he wants a probability of an event involving at least two flips, so $P(HHHTHH)$.  On the other hand, if we substitute "coin flips occurring" with "outcomes", then it would "a specific set of outcomes", and that can be *any* event (i.e. *any subset of the sample space $\Omega$*).

Comment: If the question had been written with the right terminology and symbols, concepts could have been explained much easier and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it is looking for the probability of a head in $6^{\text{th}}$ flip, conditional on the first 5 outcomes. This can be done from the definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}.$$

In this case, $A=\{\text{Head on the }6^{\text{th}}\text{ flip}\}$ and $B=\{(H,H,H,T,H)\}.$

If the flips are independent, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=p^5(1-p)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)=p^4(1-p),$ and so $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=p=\mathbb{P}(A).$

This may not be the case if the flips are not independent.

Comment: Forgive me but I really suck at interpreting formulas, is there any chance you could explain with examples and without using formulas?

Comment: [Here is an example of conditional probability.](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/what-is-conditional-probability/)

Comment: In elementary set theory, $\{a,a\} = \{a\}$, so it's better to write $B = \{(\dots)\}$ instead of $B = \{\dots\}$, since probability theory makes use of symbols from set theory.

Answer (score 1):

## A short (informal, high-school level) answer

Since each flip is independent, the probability that the 6th flip is Head is *independent* from the previous five flips, so the required probability is just $\dfrac35$.

## A *formal* answer from [probability-theory](/questions/tagged/probability-theory)

My probability professor tells us to make the *sample space* $\Omega$ clear *first* before solving any [probability](/questions/tagged/probability) problems.  The set $\Omega$ represents all *a priori* possible outcomes (of the six flips).
$$\Omega = \{H,T\}^6$$
Your target *event* is $$E = \{(F_1,\dots,F_6) \in \Omega \mid F_6 = H\}.$$
Your probability $P:{\cal P}(\Omega) \to [0,1]$ defined from *elementary events* (i.e. events that are *elements* of $\Omega$)
$$P(\{F_1,\dots,F_6\}) = p^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,6\} \mid F_i = H\}} \, q^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,6\} \mid F_i = T\}}, \tag{*}\label{*}$$
where $p = \dfrac35$ and $q = \dfrac25$ are numbers that you've set.

- $F_i$ means the $i$-th flip, with $i$ ranging from $1$ to $6$ inclusive.
- For each single outcome $(F_1,\dots,F_6) \in \Omega$, $\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,6\} \mid F_i = H\}$ counts the number of Heads occurred.  Idem for $\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,6\} \mid F_i = T\}$.

Therefore, sum up these elementary events to get
\begin{align}
P(E) &= P\left(\bigcup_{(F_1,\dots,F_5) \in \{H,T\}^5} \{F_1,\dots,F_5,H\} \right) \tag{definition of $E$} \\
&= \sum_{(F_1,\dots,F_5) \in \{H,T\}^5} P(\{F_1,\dots,F_5,H\}) \tag1\label1 \\
&= \sum_{(F_1,\dots,F_5) \in \{H,T\}^5} p^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = H\} + 1} \, q^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = T\}} \tag2\label2 \\
&= p \, \sum_{(F_1,\dots,F_5) \in \{H,T\}^5} p^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = H\}} \, q^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = T\}} \tag3\label3 \\
&= p \, (p + q)^5 \tag4\label4 \\
&= p \, (1)^5 = p,
\end{align}
which is as expected.  Note that the both sides of the above equality *don't* depend on the outcomes of the first five flips $(F_1,\dots,F_5)$.

Explanations for the above steps:

1. decompose $E$ into *elementary events* for calculations with $P$.  (i.e. split $E$ into a union of $6^5$ possible cases according to the first five flips.)
2. definition \eqref{*} applied with $F_6 = H$, which accounts for $+1$ in the exponent of $p$.
3. $p$ factored out of the summation sign.
4. basic combinatorics

   - LHS $\sum\limits_{(F_1,\dots,F_5) \in \{H,T\}^5} p^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = H\}} \, q^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = T\}}$: for each $5$-tuple $(F_1,\dots,F_5)$, the product $p^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = H\}} \, q^{\#\{i \in \{1,\dots,5\} \mid F_i = T\}}$ can be regrouped by the counting the occurrences of $p$ and $q$.  (e.g. $pqpqp = p^3\,q^2$)
   - RHS $= \underbrace{(p+q)\cdots(p+q)}_{5 \text{ times}}$: choose among $p$ and $q$ *five* times to form a product, and *sum* all possible choices up.

Further reading: definitons of axiomatic probability in [*Foundations of the Theory of Probability*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c3e1/51f71168a5f348bdebfde11752ca603fa6d0.pdf) by A. N. Kolmogorov (Chap I, section 1)

Remarks: The specific settings of this question (say $6$, $0.4$, $0.6$, $HHHTH$) are *irrelevant* to the general problem ([independence](/questions/tagged/independence) of flip).